# Is it possible to send an email to all my site members?

Tags: email

I am using sp2010. Is it possible to send an email to all site members?

Comment: When do you need to send the email? What are the approaches you are free to take? Write some C# code? or fully OOTB? workflows?

Comment: http://farhanfaiz.wordpress.com/2008/05/29/moss-end-email-to-all-site-users/

Comment: In c# it is easy, but we dont want developed solutions. Something OOTB or in a workflow is OK.